# Qt6 and qextserialport

Tags: qt, qt6, qextserialport

I use qextserialport a lot for knocking up little test programs. I'm an embedded C engineer rather than GUI/C++ type of person, but have just about enough ability to knock up Mickey Mouse Qt programs for testing embedded systems.

I've started writing a program using Qt6 for the first time and am having a problem with getting errors in some of the qextserialport source, where it's telling me that QRegExp is not found.

A quick Google gives a hit on this web site saying that QRegExp is depricated and we should now use
QRegularExpression. Howver, even going against all training and attmepting to mod a third party library, using QRegularExpression brings up a whole host of extra issues.

I've tried Googling Qt6 qextserialprt and not found a single hit which I find unlikely.

Is anyone able to advise on whether qextserialort is now unusable with Qt6 and should be using QtSerialPort maybe? I cannot see any qextserialport newer than what I have and the web site says:

> QextSerialPort can be used with Qt2, Qt3, Qt4 and Qt5.

Does QtSerialPort work as well as qextserialport? I have so many apps using the latter, would be a ral pain to have to change them all.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://www.qt.io/blog/porting-from-qt-5-to-qt-6-using-qt5compat-library

Comment: Thanks, I am currently down this rabbit hole trying to install the compatibility libs.

Comment: 1. See if QtSerialPort can be a drop-in replacement, or a replacement by making a simple wrapper for old API. 2. See if qextserailport can be built for Qt 6 with qt5compat. 3. Stick with Qt 5 for as long as you can, hope for a port or wrapper.

Comment: Thanks.

I have, apparently, got the compatibility libs installed, but it makes no difference. 

Looks like you can install 5.12 so am going to give that a go to help me limp along for the time being for this Windows app, but when the next version of my Linux distro comes out you can bet that will be 6.x only. There doesn't seem to have been any qextetserial port dev done for years and years. You'd hope they'd unpdate that really.

Comment: At least QRegExp should work with qt5compat, right? Also, if you fon't have a module installed, you should probably get an error as soon as you add it to the project.

Comment: Installing 5.12 has me going. 

I thought I'd installed the compatibility libs, but Creator thinks otherwise!

Comment: What has QExtSerialPort which does QSerialPort not provide?

Comment: I have no idea, I've never used QSeralPort. Maybe it's better. Maybes it's "drop in". The next project I do I'll try it and see how well it works.

Comment: Start here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialport-index.html